# How does ping which do not use a tcp/udp port work in a pat ( nat overload) network?

Tags: networking, routes, nat

I sit behind a nat network and i am able to ping 8.8.8.8. I know that normal tcp/udp packets gets assigned a inside global address and  random port and all incoming packets to this port will be forwarded back to me. How does ICMP packets which do not use any tcp/udp ports work in pat. How will the ICMP echo reply will be forwarded to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practise for this is described in [RFC 5508](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5508#section-3).

In a nutshell, NATs associate each ICMP-query with a query ID that is bound to the host who originated the query. The answer then gets mapped back on arrival. They use the IP header for this mapping.